# Use lark to analyze reST markup language like sections

Tags: python, restructuredtext, lark

I would like to define one basic grammar such as to start to work with `lark`. Here is my M(not)WE.

```py
from lark import Lark

GRAMMAR = r"""
?start: _NL* (day_heading)*

day_heading : "==" _NL day_nb _NL "==" _NL+ (paragraph _NL)*
day_nb      : /\d{2}/
paragraph   : /[^\n={2}]+/ (_NL+ paragraph)*
_NL         : /(\r?\n[\t ]*)+/
"""

parser = Lark(GRAMMAR)

tree = parser.parse("""


==
12
==

Bla, bla
Bli, Bli



Blu, Blu


==
10
==


Blo, blo


    """)

print(tree.pretty())
```

This prints :

```
start
  day_heading
    day_nb      12
    paragraph
      Bla, bla
      paragraph
        Bli, Bli
        paragraph       Blu, Blu
  day_heading
    day_nb      10
    paragraph   Blo, blo
```

The tree I want is the following one.

```
start
  day_heading
    day_nb      12
    paragraph
      line      Bla, bla
      line      Bli, Bli
      line      Blu, Blu
  day_heading
    day_nb      10
    paragraph
      line      Blo, blo
```

How can I modify my EBNF?

Comment: You could start with this [JSON parser tutorial](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_tutorial.html) in the official docs. And if you face any roadblocks you could post a more specific question.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible answer: I have misused a recursive rule in my initial question.

Replacing `_NL` by `NL` allows to keep the new lines.

```py
from lark import Lark

GRAMMAR = r"""
?start: _NL* (day_heading)*

day_heading : "==" _NL day_nb _NL "==" _NL+ (paragraph)+
day_nb      : /\d{2}/

paragraph : (line _NL)+

line : /[^\n={2}]+/
_NL  : /(\r?\n[\t ]*)+/
"""

parser = Lark(GRAMMAR)

tree = parser.parse("""


==
12
==

Bla, bla
Bli, Bli



Blu, Blu


==
10
==


Blo, blo


    """)

print(tree.pretty())
```

This produces:

```
start
  day_heading
    day_nb      12
    paragraph
      line      Bla, bla
      line      Bli, Bli
      line      Blu, Blu
  day_heading
    day_nb      10
    paragraph
      line      Blo, blo
```